A question about coherent sheaves over projective spaces $kP^n$
A category $\mathcal A$ is called finitary if any two objects $M,N\in \mathcal A$ satisfies the following conditions:

$|Ext^1(M,N)|<\infty$
$|Hom(M,N)|<\infty$

For the category $Coh(k\mathbb{P}^n)$ of coherent sheaves over projective space $k\mathbb{P}^n$, where $k$ is a field. By Serre, $$\text{dim } Ext^i(M,N)<\infty \text{ for any } M,N\in Coh(k\mathbb{P}^n) $$
so for $k=\mathbb{F}_q$, $|Ext^1(M,N)|<\infty$. But why $|Hom(M,N)|<\infty$ is not satisfied for $M,N\in Coh(\mathbb{F}_q\mathbb{P}^n)$?

I guess it is satisfied. Could you give a reference for the statement on $\mathrm{Ext}^1$?

@LeoAlonso, maybe I am wrong. I have read that the only finitary category is the case of $Coh(\mathbb{F}_q\mathbb{P}^1)$.  I just assumed by Serre, then $|Ext^1(M,N)|<\infty$, so the problem would happen to $Hom$

@LeoAlonso, could you tell me why you think $|Hom(M,N)|<\infty$?

On any projective variety $X$ over a field $k$, say, the sheaf $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ is coherent whenever $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ are coherent. Now,
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) \cong \Gamma(X,\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}))
$$
And the global sections of a coherent sheaf is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space. See Hartshorne, chap II, Theorem 5.19.
For higher Exts you may use the derived version of this fact.
